# fmdb fmresultset not loading anything

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, fmdb

some friends and me are developing a game in cocos2d :), and im using fmdb for some settings in it. Actually i have this code :

---

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myDB" ofType:@"sqlite"];

mainDB = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:path];

```
if ([mainDB open])
    NSLog(@"did open db");
else 
    NSLog(@"did not open db");

_stages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[mainDB open];

FMResultSet *FResult = [mainDB executeQuery:@"select * from stagesTable"];

NSLog(@"columns : %d",[FResult columnCount]);
```

if ([FResult next])
            NSLog(@"have objects");
    else
             NSLog(@"dont have objects");

```
NSLog(@"with %d objects",[_stages count]);

[mainDB close];
```

---

But FResult is not storing anything, mainDB does open, but columns are 0 objects are 0 and it always says that it doesnt have any objects.   What could be wrong?    Thanks :D !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `logsErrors=YES;` on your `mainDB`and watch the output on the console.

You never populate _stages so that will always have zero objects in it..

Comment: ty, the problem was that i wasnt adding the db to the bundle, realized by logsErrors :) !